# How to understand the `surface` of a software UI?

Tags: meaning

When I read the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/ux-guidelines/overview).

> The Secondary Sidebar also functions as a surface for rendering a View Container with Views. Users can drag views like the Terminal or the Problems view to the Secondary Sidebar to customize their layout.

What's the meaning of `surface` in there?

In my understanding of it:
[image]

surface means the outermost of an object which touches the air.

how to understand `surface` in software's UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, **surface** simply means **area of the screen**. In this case, that specific area is the sidebar. The sidebar can be moved around on the screen, so perhaps that's why it's referred to as a surface.

A graphics person would probably call it a **layer**.

Unless there's some new kind of usage because of the Microsoft Surface machines, I don't think it's described very often as a surface.